# Is there any way to get data from the database without using async/await in Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nestjs

Is there any way to use callback function for getting the data from the database using typeorm in nest.js and process that data, after that I want to send a response.

Comment: `.then()`, but why would you want to?

Comment: I want to return the service function output from the callback of the query. If we use await for the query that much time our system execution wait for its output and not doing another task.

Comment: I don't think you're using await correctly, if that's the case.

Comment: In the case of duplicate value in the primary key, In await, how can I catch the error of a query?

Comment: A simple `try`/`catch` around your `await`s will do.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understood your question correctly, but out of the box, you can use TypeORM (assuming you use a SQL DB, Mongoose works similarly, though). The repository functions return a `Promise<>`, so you could use something like this (from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)):

```
return this.photoRepository
           .find()
           .then(result => {//... your callback code goes here...
            });
```

You could wrap this code in a `function getModifiedResult(cb){}` and pass the callback into it. Secondly, Remember that `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for promises, so the above is equivalent to:

```
result = await this.photoRepository.find();
cbAction = //... do something with your result here
return cbAction;
```

Again, you could just wrap this.
Another idea is to wrap the promise in an Observable, using the RxJS `from` operator (`fromPromise` for RxJS versions < 6). You can then put your callback into the subscription:

```
//... Note that this returns a subscription for you to unsubscribe.
return from(this.photoRepository
           .find()
           .then(result => result))
           .subscribe(result => //... your callback code
            );
```

If you go down that route, however, it may be worthwhile to modify your results using RxJS operators, like `map, switchMap,...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the from/of operators from rxjs.
Example

```
create(user: UserInterface): Observable<UserInterface> {
    return from(this.userRepository.save(newUser))
}
```

And if you want you can also pipe the outcome

```
create(user: UserInterface): Observable<UserInterface> {
    return from(this.userRepository.save(user)).pipe(
          map((user: UserInterface) => user))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can use observables and / or promises (async await).  I often use an observable for the wrapper function and then promises for addition work in a pipe.  I'm not sure why I don't use observables for everything but it doesn't matter.

TypeORM integrates nicely with Nestjs and the docs show how to do the basics.  With Postgres there is a problem with arrays that I'm trying to figure out though.  An SO post and a Github issue have gone unanswered.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think Observables are great and incredibly powerful, but I'm not sure wrapping the database call in an observable is the kind of answer OP is looking for. I assume they're looking more for something like `myRepository.create(myObject, (err, result) => {})` style of callbacks.

Comment: Jay, I always respect your opinions.  But I worked it out with an observable a few weeks ago.  I did some refactoring and went back to a promise because I already had that code.  I'm so bad a dev that I copy and paste my older code and reuse it instead of taking a fresh perspective each time.
:-)

Comment: I have no problems with using Observables or promises, I actually very much enjoy using both of them. Most of my NestJS server is running with Observables. All I'm saying is that it seems that OP was looking for the regular style of callbacks, passing a function for errors and done-ness, instead of wrapping a promise function in an Observable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TypeORM, along with most modern JS packages, have been built with only promises in mind. Callbacks are, for the most part, not used in many programs today unless absolutely necessary, as promises and `async/await` syntax make the code much cleaner and more readable than the possible callback hell you may enter when using callbacks. It does look like [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) accepts callbacks, and there are some docs in the recipes section about [how to use NestJS with Sequelize](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-sequelize)

Comment: Nestjs and TypeORM both use Observables.

Comment: Observables, yes, but general callbacks, no. RxJS is considered to be different than JavaScript callbacks by many (myself included).

Answer (score 0):

This is not much to do with Nest itself, it's just how you write your code and handle whatever libraries you might have. Let's say you have your database fetching function with a callback:

```
function findUsersWithCallback(function callback() {
  // do something with db
  callback(err, results);
});
```

You can wrap this into a promise-like function with, say, `util.promisify`

```
const findUsersPromisified = require('util').promisify(findUsersWithCallback);
```

What's left is to use your standard Nest provider:

```
@Injectable() UsersService {
  findUsers() {
    return findUsersPromisified();
  }
}
```

Now your UsersService behaves like the rest of the framework, and your old callback-based code is nicely wrapped so you can safely ignore it.